# Cakephp progressbar in view and update from controller

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have a fileupload ready where I upload an xml file and the controller is importing it to the database and checks for double values etc.

This task inside my controller takes a while. I am dealing with 30Mb files.

So since it's taking a little bit long, I would love for the user to see a progressbar, from the progress of the function from the controller.

Since cakephp is mvc-architecture, I am not sure if that is even possible.

I searched different pages and found some ajax, jquery php stuff, but I could not really adjust it, so it works with my controler and view.

Here is the controller:

```
publix index() {
        //xml import
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
           //checkfilesize
           //checkformat

            if($uploadOk)
            {
               //do stuff
               if($this->Stories->createStory($data)) {
                  array_push($success_msg,'<i>'.$data['title'].'</i> has been saved.');                             
                }
                //create error
                else {
                   array_push($warning_msg ,'<i>'.$data['title'].'</i> could not been saved');
                }
            }

$this->set(compact('xml','success_msg','info_msg','warning_msg'));  
}
```

As you can see a very basic index function.

View file:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
        70%
</div>
```

So how could I change those values from the controller?

Comment: post to ajax, and flush the php cache each time you need to update the data, + clock in js to update ur progressbar :) Or still ajax post & then ajax request to a simple progress checker, progress should be stored in session then :p

Comment: @Bob0t and how is that possible, posting values to ajax. Is it with $this-render();?

Comment: The HTML Form should be catched with something like Jquery, on submit, better than posting normally, you gather form data & post it in ajax (the script which processing data should store in a file the progress), at the same time, you open a loading bar dialog, and a new ajax request to a page which will gather the progress value 2 times per second for example. You understand what is the idea ? I'm sorry I dont have time to make you a complete answer ... will do it if I have time